# double.IsNaN - What is the compiler doing here

Tags: c#

When we do something like `double.IsNaN` -- what exactly is happening?

If `double` was a class I would understand it, but double is a struct and it is a value type so how does C# actually call a static method on a value type?

Comment: What is the question? Structs and classes both can have static methods

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Structs can have methods.

...

Just incase an example is required:

```
struct Foo {
    public void Hey ()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("hey");
    }

    public static void DoSomething ()
    {
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Comment: To be more specific. structs can also have STATIC methods. It calls this static method - which checks whether the bits in the double struct are identical to those indicating a NAN.

Answer (score 2):

NaN = Not A Number.

It is something that is built into the float/double standard and implemented in the processor itself. See more at http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/coding/ieeefloat.html.

Answer (score 0):

From here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/clr/thread/16ffdb1f-119c-407e-b9f7-b9c79fec0e94/

> Actually when you invoke the static
>   method of a structure, the following
>   steps happen before the call: 
>   1.The CLR initialize the runtime type information structure called  a
>   CORINFO_CLASS_STRUCT contains several
>   critical pieces of the type including
>   the static method pointer.
>
> 2.Your calling to the static method will be routed to the method
>   instruments complied by the JIT(if
>   your assemlby not nGENed).
>
> In this process, no constructor
>   involved.

Answer (score 0):

All data types inherit from the `Object` base type, so any data type has object-like behaviour in the sense that it can have methods and properties.

A structure like `Double` doesn't inherit directly from `Object` but from `ValueType`, which make the compiler treat the data type as a simple value. This changes how the data is stored, and it limits the object capabilities somewhat. A structure can for example not have virtual methods, as the data is not decorated with a pointer to a virtual method table like an object is. A structure can still have regular methods and properties, though.